# Kubernetes : WARN datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: namenode:9001

Tags: kubernetes, hadoop

I am a novice to Kubernetes and I currently trying to deploy hadoop in kubernetes. I follow that docker-compose to deploy h https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose-v3.yml Below there is my yaml for the namenode :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hadoop-namenode
  labels:
    traefik.docker.network: hbase-namenode
    traefik.port: "9870"
  namespace: hdfs
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hadoop-namenode
      traefik.docker.network: hbase-namenode
      traefik.port: "9870"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hadoop-namenode
        traefik.docker.network: hbase-namenode
        traefik.port: "9870"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: data-mesh-hdfs
      containers:
      - name: hadoop-namenode
        image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9870
        env:
          - name: CLUSTER_NAME
            value: test
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
             name: hadoop-secret
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data-namenode
            mountPath: /hadoop/dfs/name
      volumes:
        - name: data-namenode
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: namenode-pvc
```

I create the pv and pvc for my pod and I attach my service on the pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-namenode
  namespace: hdfs
spec:
  selector:
    traefik.docker.network: hbase-namenode
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: namenode
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9870
      targetPort: 9870
```

When I deploy my pod hadoop-namenode, he was up and running correctly on my cluster. I had those logs :

```
2021-12-14 15:43:25,893 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2021-12-14 15:43:26,044 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode []
2021-12-14 15:43:26,202 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2021-12-14 15:43:26,367 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2021-12-14 15:43:26,368 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2021-12-14 15:43:26,422 INFO namenode.NameNodeUtils: fs.defaultFS is hdfs://namenode:9001
2021-12-14 15:43:26,423 INFO namenode.NameNode: Clients should use namenode:9001 to access this namenode/service.
2021-12-14 15:43:26,634 INFO util.JvmPauseMonitor: Starting JVM pause monitor
2021-12-14 15:43:26,676 INFO hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting Web-server for hdfs at: http://0.0.0.0:9870
```

And finally when i setup my datanode and service using this file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hadoop-datanode
  labels:
    traefik.docker.network: hbase-datanode
    traefik.port: "9864"
  namespace: hdfs
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hadoop-datanode
      traefik.docker.network: hbase-datanode
      traefik.port: "9864"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hadoop-datanode
        traefik.docker.network: hbase-datanode
        traefik.port: "9864"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: data-mesh-hdfs
      containers:
      - name: hadoop-datanode
        image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9864
        env:
          - name: SERVICE_PRECONDITION
            value: "10.47.0.1:9870"
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
             name: hadoop-secret
        volumeMounts:
          - name: datanode
            mountPath: /hadoop/dfs/data
      volumes:
        - name: datanode
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: datanode-pvc
```

All my pod up and running but I got this error on my datanode.

```
kubectl get pod -n hdfs
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hadoop-datanode-7f9bdb4f54-4hh6t   1/1     Running   0          2d21h
hadoop-namenode-6bddbc7b6-h8bqk    1/1     Running   0          2d22h


2021-12-17 14:46:57,697 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@4b5c304e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:41327}
2021-12-17 14:46:57,698 INFO server.Server: Started @2486ms
2021-12-17 14:46:57,943 INFO web.DatanodeHttpServer: Listening HTTP traffic on /0.0.0.0:9864
2021-12-17 14:46:57,952 INFO util.JvmPauseMonitor: Starting JVM pause monitor
2021-12-17 14:46:57,958 INFO datanode.DataNode: dnUserName = root
2021-12-17 14:46:57,958 INFO datanode.DataNode: supergroup = supergroup
2021-12-17 14:46:58,026 INFO ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 1000, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, ipcBackoff: false.
2021-12-17 14:46:58,043 INFO ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 9867
2021-12-17 14:46:58,310 INFO datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:9867
2021-12-17 14:46:58,332 INFO datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2021-12-17 14:46:58,359 WARN hdfs.DFSUtilClient: Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null. Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
2021-12-17 14:46:58,363 INFO datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2021-12-17 14:46:58,389 INFO datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to namenode:9001 starting to offer service
2021-12-17 14:46:58,408 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2021-12-17 14:46:58,409 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9867: starting
2021-12-17 14:46:58,480 WARN datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: namenode:9001
2021-12-17 14:47:03,481 WARN datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: namenode:9001
2021-12-17 14:47:08,483 WARN datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: namenode:9001
2021-12-17 14:47:13,484 WARN datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: namenode:9001
2021-12-17 14:47:18,486 WARN datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: namenode:9001
```

I use secret ressource to setup my environment variable for datanode and namenode which give that result for my datanode at the start :

```
Configuring core
 - Setting hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts=*
 - Setting fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9001
 - Setting hadoop.http.staticuser.user=root
 - Setting io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
 - Setting hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups=*
Configuring hdfs
 - Setting dfs.datanode.data.dir=file:///hadoop/dfs/data
 - Setting dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=false
 - Setting dfs.webhdfs.enabled=true
 - Setting dfs.permissions.enabled=false
Configuring yarn
 - Setting yarn.timeline-service.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-allocation-vcores=4
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.store.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage=98.5
 - Setting yarn.log.server.url=http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.fs.state-store.uri=/rmstate
 - Setting yarn.timeline-service.generic-application-history.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=resourcemanager
 - Setting yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-allocation-mb=8192
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.resource_tracker.address=resourcemanager:8031
 - Setting yarn.timeline-service.hostname=historyserver
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address=resourcemanager:8030
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.address=resourcemanager:8032
 - Setting mapred.map.output.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=/app-logs
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
 - Setting mapreduce.map.output.compress=true
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=16384
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=8
Configuring httpfs
Configuring kms
Configuring mapred
 - Setting mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3072m
 - Setting mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8192
 - Setting mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx6144m
 - Setting yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
 - Setting mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096
 - Setting mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx4096m
 - Setting mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
 - Setting mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
 - Setting mapreduce.map.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
Configuring for multihomed network
[1/100] 10.47.0.1:9001 is available.
2021-12-17 14:46:55,883 INFO datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hadoop-datanode-7f9bdb4f54-4mb8r/10.47.0.6
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 3.2.1
```

If I look at my open port on my namenode, I see this :

```
netstat -lpten
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13617204   361/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9870            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13617098   361/java
```

On my file core-site.xml on datanode, I have the data below :

```
<configuration>
<property><name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name><value>*</value></property>
<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs://namenode:9001</value></property>
<property><name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name><value>root</value></property>
<property><name>io.compression.codecs</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value></property>
<property><name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name><value>*</value></property>
</configuration>
```

Same result on the core-site.xml file of namenode :

```
<configuration>
<property><name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name><value>*</value></property>
<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs://namenode:9001</value></property>
<property><name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name><value>root</value></property>
<property><name>io.compression.codecs</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value></property>
<property><name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name><value>*</value></property>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone please help me on identifying the issue ?

Comment: My general advice is to **not** run Hadoop as containers within Kubernetes. If you need storage, use Hadoop Ozone or Minio or k8s official projects like Rook or Longhorn. You definitely do not need YARN containers within Kubernetes

Comment: I will look into what you advise me.